# Adding a layer over media player element or LibVLCSharp player

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement, mediaplayerelement

I want to add shapes like ellipse on top of the video.
right now if i add a shape over the media player element i can see it in the wpf desinger
but can not see it in runtime.

```
   <Grid>

        <controls:MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement"
            Source="https://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary-srt_eng-srt_por-srt_swe.mkv"
            AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="155"  Width="273" Fill="Black" Opacity="100" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

same with the VLClibSharp player. the only diffrence is that with this player i dont see the shape in the wpf designer.

how can i make the shapes seen in runtime?

Comment: maybe make sure the z-index is good,

Comment: i tried, the thing is that the moment the media player starting is taking over the whole page..

Comment: There is obviously a control override ocurring, check to see if the player libraries themselves have the ability for a watermark or overlay.